# How to check if my discord bot already dmed a person and it wont dm the person again (discord.py)

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I have a discord bot that handles with alts, i'm looking for a way that my bot knows if he dmed the person already before (explaining why he was kicked) and it wont dm them again. My function is like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.guild.text_channels[0]
    if something
        await channel.send(f"**{member.display_name}** was kicked")
        await member.send("**Hi, your account was kicked due to reason** \n"
            "**please try again later!**\n"
         f"**{member.guild.name}.**")

        await member.kick(reason=None)

    else:
        pass
```

My problem is that every time someone is kicked my bot dms them and I want it to dm the user kicked only once in their lifetime (without saving which user was dmed before).

would like to get help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) but you should at least save their id's to a text file.

Comment: so like, imma get the dm channel and check if my message history of this channel is 1? 
i think saving the id of the user is useless, better that my bot checks if he dmed person already somehow

Comment: @OBZ No if you save it to a text file or a json at least you then don't need to bother reading through dm channels. But yes

Comment: how do do i get bot dm channel with a member?